# JToggleButton not painting

Tags: java, swing, awt

Ok, So I make a JToggleButton:

```
JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon(features[i].getImage())) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (isSelected()) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
        }
    }
};
try {
    if (bodyButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getBody().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (eyesButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getEyes().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (glassesButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getGlasses().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (hairButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getHair().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (pantsButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getPants().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (shirtButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getShirt().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    } else if (shoesButton.isSelected()) {
        if (equals(features[i].getImage(), avatar.getShoes().getImage())) {
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

But I am having problems with it not painting. I setting selected true right after its institated as you can see, but its not painting the button **SOMETIMES**, Other times it work GREAT! Iknow that it is being set to true because I added a after it.

```
System.out.println(button.isSelected() + " " +i);
```

Comment: Post your SSCCE -   http://sscce.org that shows the problem. Also, why all all your if statements in a try block and why is the catch statement a null block of code?

Comment: Thats as short as it gets. The try and catch is because avatar.getBody().getImage() can equal null, And instead of adding null checks everywhere I decided to just surround with that...

Comment: That is not a SSCCE. You where also asked for a SSCCE when you cross posted the question here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5431292&tstart=0. So instead of expcecting people to try and duplicate your problem, do some work yourself and isolate the problem with a SSCCE. trashgod has already proven that properly written code does in fact work properly. We can't guess what is different from your code and the SSCCE provide below.

Answer (score 4):

I might override `paintComponent()` in `JToggleButton`, or perhaps just use `setIcon()`.

Addendum: Be sure you're running on the EDT and overriding `paintComponent()` correctly. The following short, complete, compilable example ([sscce](http://sscce.org/)) works reliably for me. As @camickr suggested, creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may help isolate a problem you encounter.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewMain extends JPanel {

    public NewMain() {
        super(true);
        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("test.gif")) {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
            }
        };
        this.add(button);
    }

    private static void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            f.add(new NewMain());
        }
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tryed Paint Component, No Luck, and SetIcon is being used already

Comment: Every-things running from action events from the EDT, so I have no idea.

Comment: Which is why YOU are supposed to create the SSCCE. We can't guess what exactly you are doing to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled across your problem while trying to solve one of mine.  Since you are using setSelected() to change the state of the button, be sure to use setSelectedIcon() to change the icon displayed when selected.  You can set it to the same value as setIcon() with expected results.